# Fatal Error Can't use method return value in write context

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

How can I fix this?

```
function _data($values){
foreach ($values as $key => $value){
    $this->_data($key)  = $value;
}
```

returns error message Fatal error:

> Can't use method return value in write context

Comment: `$this->_data()` is a method. What do you expect to happen here? Also, since `$this->_data()` expects an array, calling it with `$key` won't work either. Please update your question to include what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Perhaps `_data` is also a property and the intention is setting the array element using [] instead of () - `$this->_data[$key] = $value;`